# How to change the alfresco permission names

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I changed the in the following files but I cant access share anymore, It just show the login page but I cant login

In sitePermissionDedfinition.xml

```
<permissionSet type="st:site" expose="selected">

    <permissionGroup name="SiteManager" allowFullControl="true" expose="true" />

    <permissionGroup name="Expert" allowFullControl="false" expose="true">
    <includePermissionGroup permissionGroup="Expert" type="cm:cmobject" />
    </permissionGroup>

    <permissionGroup name="Intermediate" allowFullControl="false" expose="true">
    <includePermissionGroup permissionGroup="Intermediate" type="cm:cmobject" />
    </permissionGroup>

    <permissionGroup name="Beginner" allowFullControl="false" expose="true">
    <includePermissionGroup permissionGroup="Beginner" type="cm:cmobject" />
    </permissionGroup>

    </permissionSet>

    </permissions>
```

In permission.get_en.properties

```
## Groups
    group.Beginner=Beginner
    group.Intermediate=Intermediate
    group.Expert=Expert
    group.SiteManager=Site Managers
    group.EVERYONE=All Other Users

    ## Roles
    role.None=No privileges
    role.SiteManager=Manager privileges
    role.Expert=Expert privileges
    role.Intermediate=Intermediate privileges
    role.Beginner=Beginner privileges
    role.ReadPermissions=No privileges
```

In slingshot_en.properties

```
## Roles
    role.SiteManager=Manager
    role.Expert=Expert
    role.Intermediate=Intermediate
    role.Beginner=Beginner
    roles.readassociations=Beginner
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`In C:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\web-extension` create file named `custom-slingshot-acme-context.xml` and paste the code

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd'>

<beans>

   <bean id="cloud.custom.resources" class="org.springframework.extensions.surf.util.ResourceBundleBootstrapComponent">

      <property name="resourceBundles">

         <list>

            <value>alfresco.messages.acme</value>

         </list>

      </property>

   </bean>

</beans>
```

In `C:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\messages` create `acme.properties` and paste the code

```
## Rename Roles

role.SiteManager=Acme Manager

role.SiteCollaborator=Acme Collaborator

role.SiteContributor=Acme Contributor

role.SiteConsumer=Acme Consumer
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this one is still up to date, but it is at least a good starting point:

https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Custom_Permissions_in_Share

Take also a look into this tAlfresco issue: https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/MNT-2456

Comment: you used   <includePermissionGroup permissionGroup="Expert" type="cm:cmobject" /> but 'Expert' is not defined for cm:cmobject ...

Comment: http://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-share-development/custom-site-rolespermissions-03302012-0939
In this post the user provided the answer but I didnt understand

Comment: It is said to add the file web-extension I have two web-extension C:\Alfresco\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco and in C:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco 

In which folder should I use

Comment: As said before in some other comments to your questions it's bad practice to just change & overwrite alfresco files ... overwrite bean 'siteService_permissionBootstrap' in a custom context.xml would be a far better approach but you've to understand Spring DI first!

to answer your question you should say what low-level permission you would like to use for your roles.

web-extension comes into the game to set the correct role labels for Share. finish the basic stuff first.